# Upload video/image button not clickable on mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

May I know why the following code is not working on mobile?

```
<a class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 footer-links" ga-track-event="['button', 'click', 'uploadPhoto']" ng-model="files" ngf-select ngf-change="onFileSelect($files, $event)" ngf-multiple="false" ngf-accept="'image/*,video/*'" ngf-capture="camera" accept="image/*;video/*;capture=camera"
capture="camera">
  <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">UPLOAD</span>
  <span class="visible-xs visible-sm">UPLOAD</span>
</a>
```

This is from the browser

```
<div class="flex-row"><a class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 footer-links ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ga-track-event="['button', 'click', 'uploadPhoto']" ng-model="files" ngf-select="" ngf-change="onFileSelect($files, $event)" ngf-multiple="false" ngf-accept="'image/*,video/*'" ngf-capture="camera" accept="image/*;video/*;capture=camera" capture="camera"><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">UPLOAD MY PHOTO</span> <span class="visible-xs visible-sm">UPLOAD MY PHOTO</span> </a><a class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 footer-links ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty" ga-track-event="['button', 'click', 'uploadPhoto']" ng-model="files" ngf-select="" ngf-change="onFileSelect($files, $event)" ngf-multiple="false" ngf-accept="'image/*,video/*'" ngf-capture="camera" accept="image/*;video/*;capture=camera" capture="camera"><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">TAKE MY SNAPSHOT</span> <span class="visible-xs visible-sm">TAKE MY SNAPSHOT</span> </a><a class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 footer-links ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ga-track-event="['button', 'click', 'uploadVideo']" ng-model="files" ngf-select="" ngf-change="onFileSelect($files, $event)" ngf-multiple="false" ngf-accept="'image/*,video/*'" ngf-capture="camera" accept="image/*;video/*;capture=camera" capture="camera"><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">SHOOT MY VIDEO</span> <span class="visible-xs visible-sm">SHOOT MY VIDEO</span></a></div>
```

Comment: Could you post the complete HTML?

Comment: Doesn't work on old iPhone, or on all mobile devices?

Comment: @skobaljic I'm using iPhone6s and android. Tested both cannot

Comment: Your code does not look like [examples here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#usage). I would start with working example, than customize things one by one.